# Merging two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, merge

I need to merge any missing rows in a production mysql database from a backup database on restored to the same machine.

How can I do this whilst preserving the original primary key id's which are auto increment.

Comment: If you have inserted rows on both databases you may have clashed primary keys. It might not be possible to merge without changing the ids in one or the other database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_1 SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

which allows those rows in table_1 to supersede those in table_2 that have a matching primary key, while still inserting rows with new primary keys.

Alternatively,

```
REPLACE INTO table_1 SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

will update those rows already in table_1 with the corresponding row from table_2, while inserting rows with new primary keys.

Comment: Will the missing rows continue to use the same primary keys though or will they be auto_incremented at the end of the table and therefore not link up correctly with the rest of the tables?

Comment: They will use the same primary keys as they were given.

Answer (score 1):

```
--create a backup just in case
CREATE TABLE table_prod_sav SELECT * FROM table_prod;

--insert the missing rows
INSERT INTO table_prod (id, field) 
    SELECT b.id, b.field 
    FROM table_backup b LEFT JOIN table_prod p ON b.id = p.id
    WHERE p.id IS NULL;

--Check consistency...

--DROP TABLE table_prod_sav;
```